# Why does my form submit to my php as a url instead of the actions in the php file

Tags: php, forms, redirect

Ok I have a form with multiple submit buttons.
The coding on my php file has a header with a url depending on which form was entered.  My issue is when I submit the form( no matter which button I use) the window that pops up is not the url action assigned to that button but the php file itself.  What am I doing wrong?

the form starts of like this so that you can see if I directed it correctly

```
<form method="post" action="http://gamerzacademy.com/foodCYO.php" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="uid">
<input type="submit" name="Dish1" value="Dish1" onclick="
  this.disabled=true; 
  this.value='Gift Opened'; 
  document.FreeFoodForm.submit();">
<input type="submit" name="Dish2" value="Dish2" onclick="
  this.disabled=true; 
  this.value='Gift Opened'; 
  document.FreeFoodForm.submit();">
```

etc......

now the php file starts like this

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == "Dish1") {
    header("Location: url1".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish2'] == "Dish2") {
    header("Location: url2".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish3'] == "Dish3") {
    header("Location: url3".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
}
.....etc
?>
```

Comment: Too... many... linebreaks... Splitting HTML up like that, so every individual token is on its own line, actually *decreases* readability (IMHO)

Comment: What do you mean by 'but the php file itself'?

Comment: what is `FreeFoodForm` ? where is it ?

Comment: @everybody The Javascript is not just wrong, it is unnecessary. Think about what we actually want to achieve here, we just want to know which button the user clicked. Think how you would do this from scratch (hint: no JS required) before you answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand you DaveRandom in my form its not actually like that its all one line.  For some reason when I inputted it here it split lines and I didnt see it before submitting my query.

Comment: @Josh when one of the buttons is pressed instead of going to the url that its directed to go to it opens the php file in the browser instead.

Comment: @ZxChefHenryMinos Consider this - http://codepad.viper-7.com/9ISAal - Note: no Javascript in sight!

Comment: Might as well point out that you be using the `switch` function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting the form through Javascript. The code doesn't know which button was clicked, so the value of that button isn't posted to the form. Therefor, your form cannot see which button was clicked. If you change the method to `get`, you will see which value do or do not get posted.

I think you don't need to post from Javascript at all. Just let the button do the posting. Only the name and value of the button that was clicked will be posted.

B.t.w., you disable the button, presumably because you don't want people to press the button twice, but in your setup they still can press any other button. I think it is wise to disable all of them.

Comment: OK this is not *wrong* per-se but it is bad advice (IMHO). If you want to know which submit input the user clicked you don't need any Javascript at all - all you need to do is an `if (isset())` tree, because only the key for the input the user clicked will be present in the submitted data. Along the same lines, disabling the inputs themselves is actually counter-productive, because it prevents the keys from being sent back to the server. If you want to prevent a double-submit, register a handler to the form's `onsubmit` event which returns `false` after the first submit.

Comment: @DaveRandom. Thanks, you're right. This 'problem' shouldn't need a Javascript solution at all.

Comment: the intention of this is for a social networking game, its for a site that offers free items.  so as long as they have a code they enter it in the field and hit submit, Im just giving them an option to open more reward pages at a time since each new gift requires an additional data string in the url.  So each button has the new url with the new data string.  The code should append to the end of that url.

Comment: maybe my approach is wrong?  Every other time I do form variable urls like this they turn out fine the script runs with no issue.  First time I tried with multiple submit buttons

Comment: @DaveRandom ok if I do if(isset do I do that for all options or do I need to do if(isset then the rest else if(isset                          and should it be if(isset($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == "Dish1") or           if(isset['Dish1'] == "Dish1")

Comment: Like I said, none of the values of Dish1, Dish2 and Dish3 will be set, because the form is posted through JavaScript and not though the button, even though the button triggers the Javascript execution. Remove the onClick code from all three buttons and your code will work. Only the value of the button that is clicked will be posted, so you don't need Javascript to alter its value before posting.

Comment: @ZxChefHenryMinos Demo of what I'm talking about: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9ISAal

Comment: ok is there another option to get the submits out of Java so that the php script reads whats being submitted

Comment: First, Javascript != Java. Second, you don't need Javascript at all, but if you do, you must either explicitly set a value in a hidden field or alter the form action. The values of the buttons are not posted at all if you submit from Javascript.

Comment: @ZxChefHenryMinos In what sense? You mean you want to collect use input as well? http://codepad.viper-7.com/V6cpE4

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol and DaveRandom for the help.  It seems that the disable scripting was causing the problem.  Is there another non-java way I could perform this, making the button locked or greyed out or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. First, make sure the URLs you are sending in `header` are valid URLs.
2. Second, it looks like you have some whitespace before the `<?php` opening tag. Make sure there is **no** whitespace before the PHP opening tag. If there is, `header` won't work.

Comment: The urls are valid I tested them prior and there is no white space before <?php

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following in JavaScript:

```
this.disabled = true;
```

You effectively don't send its value to PHP.

A better idea might be an on submit handler in the form that prevents double submit.

Comment: tried isset instead of 'if' but still just opens the php file

Comment: Disabling the button might cause it not to be set actually.